# Redirect a facebook/page - Big mistake on brochure

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-page

I made a mistake on my brochure, I created a fan page for my business but on the brochure it reads facebook.com/pages/abc-company, abc-company is not the actual wording. Anyway, when the link from the brochure is typed into a browser a "Page doesn't exist" page opens up. What I want to know, is there a way to create a redirect in that, when a user types the mistaken url it will send the user to the actual fan page? I know this is a long shot but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is that you will need to create a new Fan page for the incorrect URL and then merge that page with the original page. I've not tried it myself, but Facebook should maintain the link to the merged page and redirect it to the page that you merge it with.

- First you need to register a new page, do that via [this link](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/).
- Then you might need to ask some of your colleagues or friends to like
  this new page so that you can then pick the correct short URL for it 
  (if the incorrect, printed link is a short one).
- After that, you can then follow the details on [this FB help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/249601088403018)
  for merging the page with the original - after this both URLs should 
  then go to the correct page.

Good luck!